# Error when signing PDF document with Azure Key Vault + Azure Function Apps + CA Certificate

Tags: azure, itext, digital-signature, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have built an Azure function app that is signing PDF document with iTextSharp.
This function app uses a certificate that is stored in Azure Key Vault.

When using a self signed certificate, for example one that was generated inside that vault or on my local machine, everything works great and I can see the signature details in the PDF file, but when I try use a certificate from CA, for example , a .PFX file from COMODO or digiCert that I import into the vault, the PDF signature comes out with an error.

Meaning, that when I open the signed PDF file in and click on the signature details, I get the error :

> Error during signature verification.
>
> Error encountered while validating:
>
> Internal cryptographic library error.
>
> Error Code: 0x2726

I tried to compare the working certificates with the CA certificates, and the only difference I have found, is that the keys of the working ones have the "Encrypt" key flagged and the CA ones, doesn't. This flag is not editable, or I just can't find a way to control this flag.

Please advice.

Edited : 
Please find below links to sample files.

[Working Azure key vault Certificate generated PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vlISxvyvIAw-pzrDH2JkMshVb-Sbr-52/view?usp=sharing)

[Invalid CA Certificate generated PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_TsZcRtu5If4K5pSm7d7fRLZM-E6VVDv/view?usp=sharing)

The files have to be download and opened in Acrobat in order to see the signatures.

Comment: Please share a sample signed PDF with that issue.

Comment: I have added 2 samples, one working and one with the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDF is indeed signed by a CA certificate, i.e. a certificate that may be used for issuing other certificates. (When I read your question I though your signer certificate merely was *issued* by a proper CA certificate, not that it *was* a CA certificate.)

In particular it has a key usage extension with values:

- digitalSignature,
- keyCertSign, and
- cRLSign.

Adobe, on the other hand, only accepts signer certificates with *one or more of the following*:

- nonRepudiation
- digitalSignature

if the key usage extension is present at all, confer e.g. Adobe's [Digital Signatures Guide for IT - Appendix A: Changes Across Releases](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/changes.html). Thus, the fact that your certificate also has key usage values keyCertSign and cRLSign makes it unsuitable for signing PDFs (or more exactly for PDFs signed with it to be validated by Adobe software).

As your certificate can serve as a certificate issuer, though, **you can use it to *issue a dedicated signer certificate*** which satisfies Adobe requirements for acceptable signer certificates. Don't forget to provide and advertise a CRL, though, to allow revocation checks!

---

Comment: Huge thanks for the amazingly detailed answert! really appreciate it!

Just to make sure I understand correctly, the CA certificate has the keyCertSign and cRLSign and this is what causing the cryptographic library error, while the self signed azure generated certificate doesn't have those and that the reason it's working?

Sorry for the novice questions, the certificates topic is really new to me.
How can I use my certificate to issue a dedicated certificate?
Or alternavly, how Do I get a certificate issued by a proper CA certificate instead of CA certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Just to make sure I understand correctly,"* - Yes. Adobe effectively wants end user certificates for signing, not ca certificates. *"How can I use my certificate to issue a dedicated certificate"* - There are numerous tools for pki management, like xpki, for such tasks. *"how Do I get a certificate issued by a proper CA certificate instead of CA certificate?"* - actually it is surprising you have such a ca certificate at all. Regular certificates should be easier to get.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I looked for days to find a certificate I need, and eventually the support of both digiCert and Comodo told me that this is the certificate I need.

I have not need in this type of certificate since I don't have to issue other certificates, just to use one to sign PDF document.

Do you have link or an exact certificate type/name that will make it work for me? I have not idea which certificate to purchase!

And again, huge thanks. I have spent dozens of hours on this issue and on chats with support representatives... :(